# Getting images URL from Amazon S3 is extremely slow on Heroku

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I have a Django app deployed on Heroku, where users submit images via Amazon S3.

Though, when serving the image using `{{ image.url }}` in my Django template, the server seems to request a signed URL from S3 for every single image, and this takes a few seconds for each image, making the site painfully slow (17 seconds to load 9 small  images).

I can see the request for each image in the logs:

```
Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=True, method=GET, url=https://x.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/x.jpg, ...>
```

Is there a way of serving the images **without** waiting for a response from S3? **How can I optimize this?**

Here is my S3 config in `settings.py`:

```py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "x"
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

#### UPDATE

I managed to make all images in the S3 bucket public, and not sign images by adding `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False` to my settings.py file, but it is still querying S3 and taking forever to load.

Comment: Do you have to use pre-signed URLS? Can you server your images from AWS CloudFront?

Comment: I am trying not to use signed URLs, because the signing process is too slow. And I need to use S3 since these are user-submitted images, potentially taking up a lot of space.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the signing process is too slow? Signing a URL takes virtual no time at all. There's no interaction with the S3 service. Are you doing this for 1000s of S3 objects? Or are you actually talking about the time taken to download the objects from S3 to the client?

Comment: You are right, this is not about signing. 
It seems it’s downloading the objects from S3 to the server THEN the server replies to the client (taking about 1.5 seconds per image, and images are loaded 10 by 10, which makes the page unusable).

Comment: Why are the S3 objects being downloaded to your server? If you're supplying S3 URLs (pre-signed or not) to the client, there doesn't seem to be any need to download objects to your server.

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out.
See the logs in my post above:
`Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=True, method=GET, url=https://x.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/x.jpg, ...>`

The server is sending requests to S3, blocking the response. I want to prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

I called `image.height` and `image.width` for each image, causing the server to download every image twice to get those values.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the latency is caused by establishing a new connection for each image. I recommend to maintain the socket open to allow faster subsequent download and only pay the connection cost once. The TCP_KEEPALIVE parameter should improve performance by maintaining the socket open and thus preventing the need to create a new connection each time an image is requested:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/credref/latest/refdocs/setting-global-tcp_keepalive.html